# FFT is coming to be a peak at 0 Hz frequency

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to perform the discrete fourier transform using the FFT algorithm from numpy in python to a very large dataset (more than 900k points).

Here is the original function's graph:
[image: original plot]

And here is the transform after I plot it:
[image: transform]

I've tried detrending the data using scipy's `detrend()` function and also subtracting the average from the data points. But the only difference that happens is that the thin gap at 0 Hz is gone.

I was expecting two peaks which would result from the big spike and then the little bump.

What can be causing the transform to come out this way? I have not checked if my time data points are spaced out evenly - I assumed that. The big spike's values go all the way to infinity and for the purposes of applying the FFT, I replaced those points with `sys.maxsize`. Could this somehow factor into the resulting waveform? I need to understand what is causing the resulting waveform to come out this way.

Here is my code for performing the transform and plotting it:
`channelA` and `time` are numpy arrays.

```
fY = np.fft.fft(channelA)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(channelA), time[1]-time[0])
plt.title("Transform")
plt.xlabel("Frequency / Hz")
plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(fY))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I suspect your FFT is accurate.  The signal has a very large DC component because it doesn't vary much.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, after discussing it I seem to understand that this is the correct fourier transform. Will trimming the function to 1-3 ms help get a different transform?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not much. It's been a couple days since I learned about it. I understand now why this transform is correct. Is there any way I can get a transform to analyze what's happening in 1-3 ms?

Comment: You have a very tall and steep upwards slope around t=1s. This is going to dominate your DFT. The little bump will have little effect. In any case, if you want to detect the little bump, you don’t need Fourier analysis. Use a peak detection in the time domain.